# Image List J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, lcdui, j2mepolish

Hi  i want to show image list with string in j2me and below is my code

[image]

```
   public ListImage() {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            img[i] = Image.createImage("/res/flag_" + i + ".png");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here u can see that image is in res folder and i am accessing image with /res/flag_ but i still get an error of Null Pointer Exception

```
  Using Untrusted simulated domain
 Cannot read /res/flag_0.png
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ListImage.startApp(+12)
at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletProxy.startApp(+7)
 null
null
null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at ListImage.startApp(+12)
at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletProxy.startApp(+7)
null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `J2ME`, `res` is the *Resource Directory* for any image, data, etc files. It's path is `root (/)` by default. And hence not required to use it's name in the path `/res/MyImage.png`. Instead call it as `/MyImage.png`.

**Example**:

```
Image img = Image.createImage( "/MyImage.png" );
```

**Refer to**:

1. [Developing J2ME applications with EclipseME](https://www6.software.ibm.com/developerworks/education/wi-nokia/wi-nokia-a4.pdf)
2. [J2ME Tutorial: User Interfaces with MIDP 2.0](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2005/05/03/midletUI.html)
3. [Where do I put images in J2me application](http://www.coderanch.com/t/473466/JME/Mobile/put-images-application)

Comment: Ravinder i have done what you have suggested to me but i am not getting error like   Cannot read /flag_2.png
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at javax.microedition.lcdui.List.<init>(+48)
    at ListImage.startApp(+28)
    at javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletProxy.startApp(+7)
null
null
null